# Как сделать такой коллаж для изображений в React

Tags: reactjs, scss

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такую раскладку для изображений на сайте. Данные приходят с API в формате ссылок.
Layout следующий:
Как минимум на сайте будет 5 изображений (разделены на 1 большое и 4 маленьких)
При наличии более 5 изображений, первые 5 складываются как в первом случае, остальные идут друг за другом внизу (как оставшиеся 15 изображений)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если бы просто можно было навесить изображения с локалки, было бы намного проще.

Comment: В каком формате приходят данные? С чем именно возникла сложность? Количество изображений всегда одинаково?

Comment: @SwaD сложность в том, что количество изображений будет разное, так как их будет добавлять админ у себя со стороны

Comment: Какой формат данных(дополните вопрос им) приходит с бэка? Как должно отображаться 1 изображение, а если их 2? 5? 100?

Comment: @SwaD обновил вопрос

Comment: может это стилями решать? например grid-ами и nth-child - тогда сколько и какого размера придет не очень важно будет.

Comment: Тут проще всего использовать `grid`.

Comment: Получаете данные, первые 5 расставляете по макету, а по остальным мапой пробегаете и рендерите